# Find files and exit if file no exist in powershell

Tags: powershell, file-extension, get-childitem, getfiles

Have some simple script:

```
$sql = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\files\" -Filter *.sql
```

In C:/files/ can be:

**1. No file.** (my issue)

2. One file (test.sql)
3. Multiple files. (test1.sql , test2.sql , etc)

For 3 i'm using `if ($sql.Count -gt 1 )` and its working fine. 
2 - is not so relevant.

1st one is a problem - do I have any way (method property) to  check and get error or "Exit 1" if file is not present at all at source? 
(without any if/else "magic") 
Now it's putting  path string into $sql variable, when there are no any *.sql file in folder.

Comment: `Now it's putting path string into $sql variable, when there are no any *.sql file in folder` I cannot replicate this, you should have an empty array if no files are found, therefore you should be able to exit using `if ($sql.count -eq 0)`

Comment: @Sinai R. : What have you tried? Please post the code you wrote.

Comment: Hi, I think BenH've answered below. There are empty array. Its my problem. :) If I want to "Get" something and there are nothing, I suppose to see an error. Maybe there are another method to get files. Without if/else. That's a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` doesn't error when there are no files matching the filter but simply returns an empty array. Because of this you cannot force a terminating error with `-ErrorAction Stop`

This mean that you will likely need to use a conditional. The simplest would be:

```
if (!($sql)) {throw 1}
```

An alternative would be:

```
$sql = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\files\" -Filter *.sql 
Switch ($sql.count) {
    0 { throw 1}
    1 { "One Item" }
    {$_ -gt 1} { "Multiple Items" }
    default { "Invalid input" }
 }
```

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thank you, Ben! Looks like "alternative" is better. Thank you again! :)